# Chrome Native Messaging throwing error when sending a base64 string to client

Tags: python, bash, chrome-native-messaging

Using [Chrome Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) [sample app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/nativeMessaging/app.zip) as a template am able make a system call to `bash`

```
os.system("<bash command>")
```

The requirement is to return a `base64` string from the python script

```
os.system("<bash command that returns a base64 string>")
```

which can verify returns expected result at `terminal`.

However, when adjust the code at `native-messaging-example-host` at lines `97-98` to

```
dataurl = os.system("<bash command that returns a base64 string>")
text = '{"text": "' + dataurl + '"}'
```

the application window closes and

```
Failed to connect: Error when communicating with the native messaging host.
```

is printed at the applications' HTML page.

When using the original code

```
text = '{"text": "' + self.messageContent.get() + '"}'
```

and sending the `base64` string corresponding to the output that the `bash` command outputs to the python host, the `base64` is sent back to the client. The length of the tested `base64` string is `43304`, less than the 1 MB maximum size of messages sent from the host.

Why is the application throwing an error and not sending the `base64` string from the python host to the Chromium client?

Answer (score 0):

```
import supprocess as sub
ter = sub.Popen("<bash command that returns a base64 string>",
                          shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE)
tread = cmd.communicate()[0].decode("u8")
text = '{"text": "' + tread + '"}'
```

Try This ^_^

Comment: Tried the code substituting `subprocess` for `supprocess` though the string is not sent to client. The string sent to host is echoed.